Is there a terminal command that installs both react + tailwindcss using vite
I want to install both tailwind + react with one command. Creating empty template files (copy pasting an empty tailwind installed project) makes my file system weird.
I searched for it and actually find nothing helpful. There is a create-vite-tailwind package but not working for me till it's pure html & javascript.

These commands should get you started with a Vite + TailwindCSS boilerplate
NPM
npm init vite@latest my-react-tailwind-project -- --template react
cd my-react-tailwind-project
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init -p

Yarn
yarn create vite@latest my-react-tailwind-project -- --template react
cd my-react-tailwind-project
yarn add -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
npx tailwindcss init -p

"my-react-tailwind-project" can be changed to whatever project name you choose.
You can continue with the rest of your configurations from there.

There are lots of starter projects on Github (like this one). You can explore more on Github.

First, make sure you have Node.js and npm (Node Package Manager) installed on your system.
Then, you can create a new React project with Create React App and integrate Tailwind CSS using a single command:
npx create-react-app my-tailwind-react-app --template cra-template-tailwindcss

